# controller request works fine on https and http. it should work only on https

Tags: java, http, spring-boot, https

I have a problem regarding on the controllers request from a spring boot application.

I have made a certificate in order to run the app on https. The certificate works fine, it is valid.

My main problem is when i test my methods from the controller through postman they(the url reques) work fine on https and http...*it shouldn't work on http*. Can someone help on this ?

This is my WebSecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public static final String AUTHENTICATED_HEADER_NAME = "Authenticated";
    public static final String AUTHENTICATED_TRUE = "true";
    public static final String AUTHENTICATED_FALSE = "false";

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        auth.userDetailsService(authenticationManager).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }


    @Override
    @Bean(value = "authenticationManagerBean")
    public org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class HTTPBasicSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        //todo check how we can change the root url of swagger
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/documentation**", "/configuration/**", "/v2/api-docs**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            //todo http basic allows access to all urls after login
            http
                    .httpBasic()
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .antMatcher("/api/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();

        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormLoginSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf()
                    //todo more investigation is required to check if it is safe to ignore csrf for login
                    .ignoringAntMatchers("/login")
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .permitAll()
                    .successHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) -> {
                        httpServletResponse.setHeader(AUTHENTICATED_HEADER_NAME, AUTHENTICATED_TRUE);
                    })
                    .failureHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, e) -> {
                        httpServletResponse.setHeader(AUTHENTICATED_HEADER_NAME, AUTHENTICATED_FALSE);
                        httpServletResponse.setStatus(SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                    })
                    .and()
                    .logout().permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                    .addFilterBefore(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
            http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                               AuthenticationException authException) -> {
                if (authException != null) {
                    response.setStatus(SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(3)
    public static class TestClass extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.headers()
                    .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
                    .includeSubDomains(true)
                    .maxAgeInSeconds(31536000);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my spring boot version

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>
```

Comment: p.s. the ssl is enabled

Comment: Why shouldn't it work on http.. As long as you didn't disable that it works on either connector.

Comment: well...how can i disable it to work on http ? I only want it to work on https

Comment: Possible duplicate of [heroku : spring boot acces to endpoints with https only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308813/heroku-spring-boot-acces-to-endpoints-with-https-only)

Comment: That depends... Are you using the embedded container or are you deploying to Tomcat.

Comment: i think it is embedded ...the one that spring holds.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is touching on several points:

- you can require clients to require secure channels, by adding the `security.require_ssl=true` configuration property (see [the Spring Boot reference documentation about HTTPS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html#howto-enable-https))
- or use the following  configuration snippet `http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();`
- you might want to enforce that as well with [HSTS in Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-hsts)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more in your question then? Are you using Spring security? Can you show your configuration? Which Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: i am using 1.4.2.RELEASE version of spring boot.

Comment: i cannot copy all the stuff around here because it's complaining about character length

Comment: i added some info above, can you check ?

Comment: when i am testing the url from chrome browser with http the url gets automaticaly to https, but in postman this is not happening it still remains http

Answer (score 0):

None of the above helped the situation I was in. 
I figured out that chrome (postman) was automatically transforming my http requests to https. 
On the other browsers http requests didn't worked.