# How do I force HTTPS for a Spring Boot app on Heroku?

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, heroku, https

I tried using `FORCE_HTTPS=true` and `SECURITY_REQUIRE_SSL=true` as config variables, but neither works. I know that the former is supported by Cloud Foundry, but I've confirmed with Heroku that they do not support it. The `SECURITY_REQUIRE_SSL` property is supported by Spring Boot, but maybe only for basic auth?

Comment: Found the answer in an existing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36348537/65681

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to fix this by creating an `HttpEnforcer` filter:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HttpsEnforcer implements Filter {

    private FilterConfig filterConfig;

    public static final String X_FORWARDED_PROTO = "x-forwarded-proto";

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        if (request.getHeader(X_FORWARDED_PROTO) != null) {
            if (request.getHeader(X_FORWARDED_PROTO).indexOf("https") != 0) {
                String pathInfo = (request.getPathInfo() != null) ? request.getPathInfo() : "";
                response.sendRedirect("https://" + request.getServerName() + pathInfo);
                return;
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // nothing
    }
}
```

And registering it in an existing `@Configuration` class.

```
@Bean
public Filter httpsEnforcerFilter(){
    return new HttpsEnforcer();
}
```

This is different from the solution I posted in the comments above because of the null check for pathInfo. Without this, it still works, but the `Location` does show up with `null` at the end.

```
$ curl -i http://www.21-points.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Pragma: no-cache
Location: https://www.21-points.comnull
Date: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 14:33:26 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 0
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

Comment: can we implement with jhipster with angular 4. if you have any repo please share.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the docs on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preparing-a-spring-boot-app-for-production-on-heroku#force-the-use-of-https) this should be all you need:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requiresChannel()
      .requestMatchers(r -> r.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto") != null)
      .requiresSecure();
  }
}
```

---

> #### Force the use of HTTPS
>
> Unless you have very specific needs, your app should be using HTTPS for all requests. Heroku provides an HTTPS URL (in the form https://.herokuapp.com) for every app, as well as free tools for adding your own domains and certificates.
>
> You can enforce the use of HTTPS when your app is running on Heroku by adding the following configuration to your Spring Boot app.

Comment: Great tip Stefan! This works and requires much less code.

Comment: With this code I can't use it locally anymore, because it tries to force https on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using spring boot, you have to add dependency to your project

for maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.createam-labs</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-heroku</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

or for gradle

```
compile('io.github.createam-labs:spring-boot-starter-heroku:1.1')
```

and then enable https enforcing in `application.properties` file by adding following line

```
heroku.enforceHttps=true
```

For more information you can visit my project site 
https://github.com/createam-labs/spring-boot-starter-heroku

Comment: Works nice. Except the documentation on github says: 
`heroku.enforceHttps=true`


instead of:

`heroku.thymeleaf.enforceHttps=true`

Comment: Yup, because github docs is about latest version, I updated this answer to be up to date :)